# Node RED: How to save data into a local csv file using file node and access it?

Tags: node-red

I am a beginner to programming. The problem I have now is that I want to store the payload in NodeRED into a local csv file. The picture showed how I was trying to do.

Basically I created a file node, and entered my local directory with filename. But it either gave me the error 'cannot find such a directory or file', or I don't get the error but I don't know where to find the file either.

My guess is NodeRED could not access local file somehow..maybe the csv will be saved in the server but how could I access it?

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What OS are you on? That looks like an OS X path, but without the `/` symbol at the start. I wonder if that needs to be `/Users/Roy/...`?

Comment: @halfer Thanks for editing the question! I am on OS10.13.3 . I tryied this path (/Users/Roy/..), but this will give an error that 'cannot find such a directory or file', if I use the path without slash, there is no error but I cannot find the file..

Comment: I did some google where people said deploying the file out node, it would give a path but in my case I did not see it...

Comment: If you use the relative path `Users/Roy/Documents/data.csv`, it will look for a directory called `Users` under the current working directory. Normally, that would be the `.node-red` (hidden) directory underneath your home directory. But to verify the current directory, check the node-red console log output -- at startup it will print that out for you.

Comment: @SteveR Thanks for the response! I kind of found the problem that I was using Node-RED on a server instead of on my computer. So I was not running it in the terminal...When I deployed the code, there was no output in the console :( Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Then the node-red logs will be on the server machine, as will the csv files you created. Do you have a login at the OS level for the server machine? If not, and you want to save the csv file locally on your own computer, you will need to deploy a flow on the server that retrieves the file contents and sends it back to you through http.

Comment: @SteveR Very clear explanation. Thanks! I will try to do that :)